# How do you know when you should make a job change

Tags: new-job, team, career-switch, motivation

How do you know when you should make a job change? I feel like I am the most motivated member of my team. Everyone else seems to be just slogging through to get through the work day. Does this mean I should switch jobs?

Comment: do you enjoy what you do? do you feel fairly compensated? do you feel like you are growing still? Is there room for advancement?

Comment: Nobody can make this decision for you but in general, if the work is no longer interesting or fulfilling, if the environment is toxic, or the compensation is lacking start looking.

Comment: @depperm: well I feel like I am the smartest person in my team. I enjoy what I do.

Answer (score 2):

Enjoying your job and excelling at it is not generally a reason to leave.

Normally you know it's time to leave when the place is toxic, the work becomes too onerous or you need more money and they won't give you a raise.

Answer (score 0):

If you worried that team motivation level will rub off on you, it may.

IMHO it depends on what stage in your carrier you are in.
In this case, you can send a few feelers to see if you can get a better motivated team, perhaps even in your current organization

It is never a bad time to look around, in fact, you should always be appraised  on trends in your line of work and latest salary / work relation.

Takes time and effort, i know, but it worth knowing what you can get in another place in terms of team / salary / work load and technology to work on, to make a good decision

Because at this time everything is changing very fast and more information you have better you be